# Interpolating Random Points

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, interpolation

I have a list of (x,y) co-ordinates that need to be interpolated. The co-ordinates are not necessarily part of a function. Therefore, polynomial interpolation will not work. Is there a way to use some other form of interpolation that doesn't need the co-ordinates to be part of a function, i.e. a form of interpolation that gives out coefficients of a pair of parametric equations, one for x-coordinates and one for y-coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean by *coordinates are part of a function*?

Comment: What I meant was that the co-ordinates that need to be interpolated cannot be expressed as a neat function y = f(x). They can only be part of a parametric equation (for eg. a circle, which is not a function in the sens that it can't be written as y = f(x) but can be written in the parametric form, x = cos(t), y = sin(t).)

Comment: Within reason, any form you write down (e.g. $(x-a)^ + (y-b)^2 = r^2$) is amenable to least squares fitting (in that simple example, just find a,b,r which minimize the least squared difference to your data).  You don't need a polynomial or other "neat" function.  It's true that you really need to have some notion of what the best fitting function is though....

Comment: Please show an example of your data. Blind answers are often wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Add some parameter $t$ to your data, so it becomes $(t_i, x_i, y_i)$ instead of $(x_i, y_i)$. The simpliest way is to take $t_i = i$. Now perform interpolation of $(t_i, x_i)$ and $(t_i, y_i)$, you'll get $x = P(t)$ and $y = Q(t)$, so your interpolation will have parametric form
$$
(x, y) = (P(t), Q(t)),\quad t \in [0, n]
$$